# how to detect favicon (shortcut icon) for any site via php?

Tags: php, javascript, regex, favicon

how to detect favicon (shortcut icon) for any site via php ?

i cant write regexp because is different in sites..

Comment: Just parse the raw HTML response of the site.. look for `<link ` in the raw string, search for `rel="icon"` there then take the value between quotes in `href="http://example.com/myicon.png"`

Comment: "Google favicon service"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use this address and drop this into a regexp

http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.example.com

This addresses the problem you were having with Regexp and the different results per domain

Comment: Never seen that before, nice :)

Answer (score 2):

You can request `http://domain.com/favicon.ico` with PHP and see if you get a 404.

If you get a 404 there, you can pass the website's DOM, looking for a different location as referenced in the `head` element by the `link` element with `rel="icon"`.

```
// Helper function to see if a url returns `200 OK`.
function $resourceExists($url) {
    $headers = get_headers($request);
    if ( ! $headers) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return (strpos($headers[0], '200') !== FALSE);
}

function domainHasFavicon($domain) {
    // In case they pass 'http://example.com/'.
    $request = rtrim($domain, '/') . '/favicon.ico';

    // Check if the favicon.ico is where it usually is.
    if (resourceExists($request)) {        
        return TRUE;
    } else {
       // If not, we'll parse the DOM and find it  
       $dom = new DOMDocument;
       $dom->loadHTML($domain);
       // Get all `link` elements that are children of `head`
       $linkElements = $dom
                       ->getElementsByTagName('head')
                       ->item(0)
                       ->getElementsByTagName('link');

       foreach($linkElements as $element) {
           if ( ! $element->hasAttribute('rel')) {
               continue;
           }
           // Split the rel up on whitespace separated because it can have `shortcut icon`.
           $rel = preg_split('/\s+/', $element->getAttribute('rel'));

           if (in_array('link', $rel)) {
               $href = $element->getAttribute('href');

               // This may be a relative URL.
               // Let's assume http, port 80 and Apache
               $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

               if (substr($href, 0, strlen($url)) !== $url) {
                   $href = $url . $href;
               }

               return resourceExists($href);
       }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

If you want the URL returned to the `favicon.ico`, it is trivial to modify the above function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$address = 'http://www.youtube.com/'
$domain = parse_url($address, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

or from a database

```
$domain = parse_url($row['address_column'], PHP_URL_HOST);
```

display with

```
<image src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain='.$domain.'" />
```